# Moving existing shop to amazon aws

Tags: amazon, hosting

So I created magento shop which already have products, customers, some orders. Now I would like to move it to amazon aws hosting. I made database dump to import all data that I have but I faced problem: I am not getting correct path when I imported my database.

For example instead of myshop.amazonaws.com/magento/js/varien/form.js

I getting url like this:

myshop.amazonaws.com/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/js/varien/form.js.

I checked httpd-prefix.conf file and it looks ok for me:

Alias /magento/ "/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/"
Alias /magento "/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs"

Does anyone have experience using amazon aws hosting for magento ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is your media/var directory writable for your webserver? thats mostly the cause for full paths in urls

see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141873/why-is-magento-1-4-including-javascript-files-by-filesystem-path

Comment: Amazing, changing media directory permissions helped me with javascript files it now shows correct path. But if I want to go to product (or admin page) or any other page I'm getting not found error. Do I have to give permissions for any other folder ?

Comment: Do you know answer to my problem I written in comment?